# Can CSS give me paragraph styling based on the previous heading class?

Tags: css, html-heading

So I want to rig up some css rules for interview transcripts.  The format I have in mind looks something like this:

```
<h2 class="interviewer">Alice: [00:00:00]</h2>
<p>Is it ok if I ask you a question now?</p>

<h2 class="interviewee">Bob: [00:00:03]</h2>
<p>Sure go ahead.</p>
```

I'd like the paragraph to be a particular colour based on the class of the preceeding heading.  Is there a way to do this, as it would make the html markup significantly simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following-sibling combinator: +

`h2.interviewer + p { /* style goes here */ }`

Comment: @JorenB: IE6 should no longer be considered. It is obsolete.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I don't really care about anything except Firefox for now :)

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
h2.interviewer + p {
    color: red;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to do it with multiple paragraphs though. Perhaps if you encased the entire set of paragraphs in a `div`:

```
<h2 class="interviewer">Alice: [00:00:00]</h2>
<div>
    <p>Is it ok if I ask you a question now?</p>
    <p>More text here.</p>
</div>

<h2 class="interviewee"> class="interviewee">Bob: [00:00:03]</h2>
<div>
    <p>Sure go ahead.</p>
</div>
```

You could then do this:

```
h2.interviewer + div {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By the way, there are better HTML elements for displaying a conversation, like the newly introduced `<dialog>` tag

http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_dialog_tag.cfm

## UPDATE:

The `<dialog>` element never made it into HTML5. It does not exist.

Comment: Interesting.  But I also want to programatically extract only text from the interviewee from the page for further processing.  This doesn't seem to have the facility to convey that relationship.

Comment: Sure it does. You can add classes to any tag. Just do `<dt class="interviewee>Bob: [00:00:00]</dt>`.

Comment: As the linked page says, <dialog> isn't in HTML5 any more.